# iphone upgrade - did it back up?

Tags: iphone, backup

**If** you tell iTunes to upgrade your iPhone from os4 to os4.versionupdate (example)...

**Does** iTunes automatically back it up before attempting upgrade?

my phone is currently in recovery mode - and I don't know whether it backed up or not (you rookie!!!)

**EDIT** I have browsed to the back up folder, i.e.

`C:\Users\<MY USERNAME>\AppData\Roaming\Apple Computer\MobileSync\Backup`

There is a folder with todays date: `\a6fbdb939e60771c51f18a68a41e8e0e2d230dcc` - would this be the backup done before attempting software upgrade?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iTunes creates a backup of your iPhone everytime you sync it, not only when you upgrade it.

If in doubt, sync the iPhone before upgrading.

Here is an Apple Support article about the subject: http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1766

Comment: ty tho did mention i had already upgraded, will always sync in future

Comment: It is not quite clear from the above link does it backup firmware too or only private data? Will a be able to restore iOS 7 from those backup after upgrading to 8.0?

Comment: That answer is from 2010. I don’t think you can upgrade to 8 now, unless you have a very old device, and even then I’m not sure the upgrade will be available. Also, I don’t think you will be able to downgrade to 7 even if you had the firmware. Apple verifies the firmware before applying the upgrade and if there is an upgrade to 8 (or any other version) then they most likely won’t be signing iOS 7 for downgrade.

Comment: But what is the rule of thumb? Can I restore to an earlier firmware via standard iCloud backup? Or it is impossible?

Answer (score 2):

iTunes definitively creates a backup before upgrading. The folder you see seems to be this backup.